# vueerror Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'use')

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to add toastr in my vue project. but I am having this error in console--

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'use')
```

this is my code in app.js---

```
import Vue from 'vue';

import './bootstrap';
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import CreateCart from './components/CreateCart.vue';

import CxltToastr from 'cxlt-vue2-toastr';
import 'cxlt-vue2-toastr/dist/css/cxlt-vue2-toastr.css'

var toastrConfigs = {
    position: 'top right',
    showDuration: 2000,
    timeOut: 5000,
   }
Vue.use(CxltToastr, toastrConfigs)
window.axios = require('axios');
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

const app = createApp({});
app.component('create-cart', CreateCart);

app.mount('#app');
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Vue 3, the correct way to do it is:

```
import { createApp } from "vue";    
import App from "./App.vue";
import CxltToastr from 'cxlt-vue2-toastr';

const app = createApp(App);

const toastrConfigs = {
 position: 'top right',
 showDuration: 2000,
 timeOut: 5000,
}
app.use(CxltToastr, toastrConfigs).mount('#app');
```

I hope it helps you